# A word to describe the probability of complying with a suggestion

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm working in a marketing context, where emails are regularly sent to our customers inviting them to perform certain activities that will help their business. I'm looking for a suitable word that describes the probability that a given customer will act upon our recommendation; some words that have been proposed are "propensity" or "conversion" but I don't find these to be right.

For example,

> When we send emails to segment X of our customers inviting them to update their profile picture, the (*probability of success?* *action propensity?* *conversion rate?*) is 43%.

Comment: Response rate? Acceptance rate? Success rate? Uptake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"When we send emails to segment X of our customers inviting them to update their profile picture, the **adoption rate** is 43%."

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [adoption](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adoption):

> : the act of adopting : the state of being adopted

And [adopt](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adopt):

> **2** : to take up and practice or use • *adopted* a moderate tone
>   **3** : to accept formally and put into effect • *adopt* a constitutional amendment

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the term *uptake*. I’ve selected a couple of examples from the dictionary entry that use the term with a percentage.

> **uptake** *noun*
>   The action of taking up or making use of something that is available.
>   ‘He welcomed the recent improved uptake in the MMR vaccine, which currently stands at around 77% of the target population.’
>   ‘It also says that free school meal uptake at primary school level is 17.9%, but nearly 22% of children are eligible.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/uptake)

To address the probability factor, you can apply terms of uncertainty between *uptake* and the percentage quoted.

Your sample sentence would look like this:

- When we send emails to segment X of our customers inviting them to update their profile picture, the **uptake** is usually about 43%.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of expressing this; [**Positive Response Rate**](https://www.acronymfinder.com/Positive-Response-Rate-(PRR).html) is easily understood and seems to be quite popular.

Answer (score 0):

A word which I think fits your need:

"compliance" means to comply:

> comply
>   1. To act in accordance with another's command, request, rule, or wish.
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/complying)
>
> comply
>  1Act in accordance with a wish or command.
>  [Oxford
>   Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/comply)

To the extent that your suggestion is a request, wish or recommendation, for someone to follow your request and take action based off it is, as per the definition, to comply.

Therefore, I think the word that's good for you is simply "compliance"

> When we send emails to segment X of our customers inviting them to
>   update their profile picture, the ( compliance / compliance rate) is 43%.

Comment: The OP is asking about an emailed invitation. Compliance is a response to an instruction or command, so it doesn’t really work here.